# JS variable containing ongoing time value

Tags: javascript, timer, counter, hubot

I'm working on a chatbot script (Hubot - running in terminal) exercise and looking for a method to count the time since the last message was left in the thread. Then after nobody has left a message for X number of minutes (let's say 10,000 milliseconds) I would like to console.log("CRICKETS!..CRICKETS!..")

I'm imagining something like:

```
//currentTime - startTime = timeSince
//and 
// if( timeSince > 10,000) 
//    {console.log("Crickets!..")
```

however I'm not sure of how to create the currentTime variable as continuously growing counter

Below is the code I've started which doesn't appear to throw any errors in the , but also doesn't seem to work as I'm running it in the terminal. It just prints the current time twice

```
module.exports = function(robot) {
  return robot.hear(/$/i, function(msg) {
    var startTime = (Date.now()) ;
    return(startTime);

  if (Date.now() - startTime > 1000) {
  console.log("CRICKETS..!...")
  };
  });
};
```

You'll notice I'm using Date.now() but I'm not attached if there's a better method. Also here is a link to basic hubot scripts in case it is needed for context - https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/docs/scripting.md

Comment: The `setTimeout` function allows you to trigger a callback function after a delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `setTimeout` and cancel it if need be

Pseudo-code:

```
var myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
   //nobody has left a message for 10 seconds
}, 10000);
if (user has left message)
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `window.setTimeout` function allows you to trigger a callback function after a delay. And you can clear that timeout by calling `window.clearTimeout(value_returned_by_setTimeout)`.

We could define a callback: `function crickets(){ console.log('Chirp! Chirp!'); }`

Assuming some function `newMessage` gets called whenever a a new message appears, you could try something like this:

```
var cricketTimeout = null;
function newMessage(){
  //... your code
  if (cricketTimeout) clearTimeout(cricketTimeout);
  cricketTimeout = setTimeout(crickets, delayInMilliseconds);
}
```